# Extract/retrieve projection from a ESRI File Geodatabase (gdb) using QGIS

Tags: qgis, getfeatureinfo

I downloaded a .gdb file (file size is 39Gb) from [FEMA Harvey Flood Depth Grid](https://web.corral.tacc.utexas.edu/nfiedata/Harvey/flood_data/FEMA_Harvey_Depths_3m.gdb.zip). As I understand, the file gdb file is used to generate the 3x3 flood depth grid shown at the attached picture.

[image: 3x3 Flood Depth Grid]

k.imgur.com/Byb3T.jpg. The picture was downloaded from [Hydroshare](https://www.hydroshare.org/resource/165e2c3e335d40949dbf501c97827837/).

For my research, I wish I could extract projections or retrieve layers from the GDB file, and export those into CSV or txt format. Using QGIS, I tried adding layer by choosing "OpenFileGDB", yet it appeared to have nothing meaningful yet. To note, I followed the guideline providing at [Mapscaping](https://mapscaping.com/working-with-esri-file-geodatabase-gdb-files-in-qgis-and-gdal/). I also tried using ArcGIS Online, yet there doesn't seem to exist a layer as I can tell for now.

Is there a way that I extract attributes or projections from the file geodatabase?

Comment: Rasters are not supported by the File Geodatabase API, though it might be able to pluck GCS_North_American_1983 (4269) geographic coordinate reference from the table. I seriously doubt you could push a 52.1GiB raster into AGOL. I have to question the wisdom of trying to generate a ~280GiB ASCII raster or 1.1TiB CSV vector layer.

Answer (score 0):

I just dragged and dropped the gdb to QGIS and this dialog pop-ed up:

[image]

I used the default selection and was able to upload the raster to QGIS.

[image]

When checking the CRS from the layer properties (you can apply the CRS on other layers or set it as the project CRS), I got the following information:

[image]

[image]

I then used gdal2xyz algorithm from the Processing Toolbox:

[image]

And used the following settings:

[image]

I had to stop processing as it was taking too long took a very long time and the result is as below:

[image]

Here are the results:

[image]

Note: The raster was huge so I had to clip it, but the process is the same:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. It perfectly fits into my purpose. I really appreciate your help.